# geth mining on 32bits host (raspberry pi) memory error

Tags: go-ethereum, dag, ethash, raspberry-pi

My objective is to create a private testnet, and mining it on a 32bits hardware (RPi3). The memory error I keep getting during DAG generation, if Im not mistaken, is excepted if I am running it on a 32bits hardware. Error log as below.

Since I am setting up an environment for testing purpose, is there a way I could remove the use of DAG from geth source completely to avoid the DAG generation error but should not affect the Proof-of-Work.

```
> miner.start(1)
INFO [08-23|07:06:46] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
INFO [08-23|07:06:46] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000
INFO [08-23|07:06:46] Starting mining operation 
null
> INFO [08-23|07:06:46] Commit new mining work                   number=1 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=2.047ms
INFO [08-23|07:06:50] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=5 elapsed=3.000s
INFO [08-23|07:06:53] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=10 elapsed=6.001s
INFO [08-23|07:06:56] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=15 elapsed=9.001s
INFO [08-23|07:06:59] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=20 elapsed=12.002s
INFO [08-23|07:07:02] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=25 elapsed=15.003s
INFO [08-23|07:07:05] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=30 elapsed=18.003s
INFO [08-23|07:07:08] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=35 elapsed=21.004s
INFO [08-23|07:07:11] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=39 elapsed=24.005s
INFO [08-23|07:07:14] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=44 elapsed=27.005s
INFO [08-23|07:07:17] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=49 elapsed=30.006s
INFO [08-23|07:07:20] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=54 elapsed=33.007s
INFO [08-23|07:07:23] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=58 elapsed=36.007s
INFO [08-23|07:07:26] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=63 elapsed=39.008s
INFO [08-23|07:07:29] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=68 elapsed=42.009s
INFO [08-23|07:07:32] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=73 elapsed=45.009s
INFO [08-23|07:07:35] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=77 elapsed=48.010s
INFO [08-23|07:07:38] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=82 elapsed=51.011s
INFO [08-23|07:07:41] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=87 elapsed=54.011s
INFO [08-23|07:07:44] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=92 elapsed=57.012s
INFO [08-23|07:07:47] Generating ethash verification cache     epoch=0 percentage=96 elapsed=1m0.012s
INFO [08-23|07:07:49] Generated ethash verification cache      epoch=0 elapsed=1m2.059s
ERROR[08-23|07:07:49] Failed to generate mapped ethash dataset epoch=0 err="cannot allocate memory"
runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 2147483648-byte block (119537664 in use)
fatal error: out of memory

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0xa2bc16, 0xd)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x78
runtime.largeAlloc(0x7ffff100, 0x11c7bd01, 0x90e2c)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/malloc.go:776 +0xc8
runtime.mallocgc.func1()
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/malloc.go:669 +0x34
runtime.systemstack(0x11320000)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:247 +0x80
runtime.mstart()
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/proc.go:1079

goroutine 31 [running]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:192 +0x4 fp=0x16db599c sp=0x16db5998
runtime.mallocgc(0x7ffff100, 0x9535b8, 0x11d12701, 0xa6afd1)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/malloc.go:670 +0xe58 fp=0x16db5a3c sp=0x16db599c
runtime.makeslice(0x9535b8, 0x1ffffc40, 0x0, 0x1ffffc40, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/slice.go:57 +0x130 fp=0x16db5a64 sp=0x16db5a3c
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash.(*dataset).generate.func1()
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash/ethash.go:285 +0xc84 fp=0x16db5c08 sp=0x16db5a64
sync.(*Once).Do(0x12502354, 0x16db5c28)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/sync/once.go:44 +0x118 fp=0x16db5c1c sp=0x16db5c08
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash.(*dataset).generate(0x12502320, 0x11546aa0, 0x10, 0x2, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash/ethash.go:294 +0x6c fp=0x16db5c40 sp=0x16db5c1c
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash.(*Ethash).dataset(0x114ee230, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash/ethash.go:539 +0x6d0 fp=0x16db5d54 sp=0x16db5c40
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash.(*Ethash).mine(0x114ee230, 0x11527cc0, 0x0, 0x81d5529, 0x5c328cc1, 0x11d1a140, 0x11d1a180)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash/sealer.go:105 +0x130 fp=0x16db5f8c sp=0x16db5d54
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash.(*Ethash).Seal.func1(0x11d12610, 0x114ee230, 0x11527cc0, 0x11d1a140, 0x11d1a180, 0x0, 0x81d5529, 0x5c328cc1)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash/sealer.go:72 +0x88 fp=0x16db5fac sp=0x16db5f8c
runtime.goexit()
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:998 +0x4 fp=0x16db5fac sp=0x16db5fac
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash.(*Ethash).Seal
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/consensus/ethash/sealer.go:73 +0x5d8

goroutine 1 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/console.(*Console).Interactive(0x117d58c0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/console/console.go:321 +0x838
main.localConsole(0x11792000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/consolecmd.go:106 +0x324
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/utils.MigrateFlags.func1(0x11792000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/utils/flags.go:1131 +0x14c
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli%2ev1.HandleAction(0x945910, 0x11477290, 0x11792000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1/app.go:485 +0xa8
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli%2ev1.Command.Run(0xa20c2c, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xa6ecb9, 0x2b, 0x0, ...)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1/command.go:193 +0xc2c
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli%2ev1.(*App).Run(0x114b0c30, 0x1130c050, 0x9, 0xa, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/gopkg.in/urfave/cli.v1/app.go:250 +0x8bc
main.main()
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth/main.go:192 +0x44

goroutine 17 [syscall, 1 minutes, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:998 +0x4

goroutine 6 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*nonrecursiveTree).dispatch(0x11310840, 0x113107c0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/tree_nonrecursive.go:36 +0x40
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify.newNonrecursiveTree
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/tree_nonrecursive.go:29 +0x1d4

goroutine 7 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*nonrecursiveTree).internal(0x11310840, 0x11310800)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/tree_nonrecursive.go:81 +0x54
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify.newNonrecursiveTree
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/tree_nonrecursive.go:30 +0x1f8

goroutine 8 [syscall, 1 minutes]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:116 +0x190
os/signal.loop()
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:22 +0x14
created by os/signal.init.1
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:28 +0x30

goroutine 9 [chan receive]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics.(*meterArbiter).tick(0x1020820)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/meter.go:221 +0x48
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics.NewMeter
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/meter.go:40 +0x19c

goroutine 34 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore.(*watcher).loop(0x114796a0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore/watch.go:91 +0x64c
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore.(*watcher).start
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore/watch.go:52 +0x4c

goroutine 18 [select, 1 minutes, locked to thread]:
runtime.gopark(0xc03fe0, 0x0, 0xa1fdc2, 0x6, 0x18, 0x2)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/proc.go:259 +0x148
runtime.selectgoImpl(0x11690790, 0x0, 0xc)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/select.go:423 +0x1368
runtime.selectgo(0x11690790)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/select.go:238 +0x10
runtime.ensureSigM.func1()
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/signal1_unix.go:304 +0x428
runtime.goexit()
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:998 +0x4

goroutine 11 [select]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.(*BlockChain).update(0x11780000)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/blockchain.go:1236 +0xd8
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.NewBlockChain
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/blockchain.go:168 +0x122c

goroutine 50 [syscall, 1 minutes]:
syscall.Syscall6(0xfc, 0xa, 0x1132278c, 0x1, 0xffffffff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x11774200, 0x1, 0x1)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/syscall/asm_linux_arm.s:48 +0x8
syscall.EpollWait(0xa, 0x1132278c, 0x1, 0x1, 0xffffffff, 0x11310b30, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/syscall/zsyscall_linux_arm.go:365 +0x90
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*inotify).loop(0x1138c000, 0x117d4000)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/watcher_inotify.go:193 +0xa4
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*inotify).lazyinit
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/watcher_inotify.go:133 +0x1f4

goroutine 51 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*inotify).send(0x1138c000, 0x117d4000)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/watcher_inotify.go:253 +0x44
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*inotify).lazyinit
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/watcher_inotify.go:136 +0x258

goroutine 52 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*inotify).send(0x1138c000, 0x117d4000)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/watcher_inotify.go:253 +0x44
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify.(*inotify).lazyinit
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/watcher_inotify.go:136 +0x258

goroutine 24 [select]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore.(*KeyStore).updater(0x117ae3f0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore/keystore.go:203 +0x188
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore.(*KeyStore).Subscribe
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore/keystore.go:190 +0x154

goroutine 25 [chan receive]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/usbwallet.(*LedgerHub).updater(0x11510820)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/usbwallet/ledger_hub.go:203 +0x54
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/usbwallet.(*LedgerHub).Subscribe
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/usbwallet/ledger_hub.go:188 +0x154

goroutine 26 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts.(*Manager).update(0x1174e400)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/manager.go:95 +0x3d8
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts.NewManager
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/manager.go:68 +0x614

goroutine 35 [select]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0x1179e210)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x260
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x258

goroutine 53 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0x11794200)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0x454
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:139 +0x574

goroutine 54 [select]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0x11794200)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:96 +0x1e4
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:140 +0x590

goroutine 55 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0x11794200)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:804 +0x63c
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:146 +0x6f4

goroutine 56 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0x11794200)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:751 +0x20c
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:147 +0x710

goroutine 12 [select]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.(*TxPool).eventLoop(0x1179e420)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/tx_pool.go:224 +0x838
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.NewTxPool
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/tx_pool.go:205 +0x5ec

goroutine 13 [select]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.(*TxPool).expirationLoop(0x1179e420)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/tx_pool.go:923 +0x460
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core.NewTxPool
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/tx_pool.go:206 +0x608

goroutine 14 [select]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.(*Downloader).qosTuner(0x1148c120)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/downloader.go:1528 +0x490
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.New
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/downloader.go:231 +0xbe0

goroutine 15 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.(*Downloader).stateFetcher(0x1148c120)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/statesync.go:74 +0x124
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.New
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/downloader.go:232 +0xbfc

goroutine 16 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.(*worker).update(0x1179e4d0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/worker.go:233 +0x64
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.newWorker
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/worker.go:142 +0x488

goroutine 66 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.(*worker).wait(0x1179e4d0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/worker.go:261 +0x60
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.newWorker
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/worker.go:144 +0x4a4

goroutine 67 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.(*Miner).update(0x115635c0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/miner.go:81 +0x160
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.New
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/miner.go:69 +0x28c

goroutine 68 [IO wait, 1 minutes]:
net.runtime_pollWait(0x75419260, 0x72, 0xf5a7e8)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/runtime/netpoll.go:160 +0x60
net.(*pollDesc).wait(0x11563cb8, 0x72, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73 +0x34
net.(*pollDesc).waitRead(0x11563cb8, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78 +0x30
net.(*netFD).accept(0x11563c80, 0x0, 0xf59a80, 0x11750180)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/net/fd_unix.go:419 +0x21c
net.(*TCPListener).accept(0x1147cf90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:132 +0x30
net.(*TCPListener).Accept(0x1147cf90, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /home/pi/meh/go1.7/src/net/tcpsock.go:222 +0xa8
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p.(*Server).listenLoop(0x117d64b0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/server.go:641 +0x260
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p.(*Server).startListening
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/server.go:432 +0x178

goroutine 69 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/nat.Map(0xf5e8d0, 0x11471b90, 0x11563a40, 0xa1ca6f, 0x3, 0x765f, 0x765f, 0xa29490, 0xc)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/nat/nat.go:114 +0x714
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p.(*Server).startListening.func1(0x117d64b0, 0x117ce1c0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/server.go:437 +0x74
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p.(*Server).startListening
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/server.go:439 +0x208

goroutine 70 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p.(*Server).run(0x117d64b0, 0xf5e880, 0x11522f00)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/server.go:501 +0x17e8
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p.(*Server).Start
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/p2p/server.go:417 +0xbd4

goroutine 71 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth.(*ProtocolManager).txBroadcastLoop(0x114ee460)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/handler.go:727 +0x4c
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth.(*ProtocolManager).Start
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/handler.go:204 +0xb4

goroutine 72 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth.(*ProtocolManager).minedBroadcastLoop(0x114ee460)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/handler.go:716 +0x54
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth.(*ProtocolManager).Start
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/handler.go:207 +0x158

goroutine 73 [select]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth.(*ProtocolManager).syncer(0x114ee460)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/sync.go:143 +0x214
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth.(*ProtocolManager).Start
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/handler.go:210 +0x174

goroutine 74 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth.(*ProtocolManager).txsyncLoop(0x114ee460)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/sync.go:109 +0x4e4
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth.(*ProtocolManager).Start
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/handler.go:211 +0x190

goroutine 75 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/contracts/release.(*ReleaseService).checker(0x11563940)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/contracts/release/release.go:118 +0x164
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/contracts/release.(*ReleaseService).Start
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/contracts/release/release.go:98 +0x38

goroutine 39 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/fetcher.(*Fetcher).loop(0x114ee4d0)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/fetcher/fetcher.go:314 +0x43c4
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/fetcher.(*Fetcher).Start
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/fetcher/fetcher.go:176 +0x2c

goroutine 76 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.(*PublicDownloaderAPI).eventLoop(0x11475180)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/api.go:63 +0x4f4
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader.NewPublicDownloaderAPI
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/downloader/api.go:49 +0x10c

goroutine 77 [select, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters.(*EventSystem).eventLoop(0x117ce240)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters/filter_system.go:407 +0x658
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters.NewEventSystem
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters/filter_system.go:100 +0x128

goroutine 78 [chan receive, 1 minutes]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters.(*PublicFilterAPI).timeoutLoop(0x113ce690)
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters/api.go:85 +0x4c
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters.NewPublicFilterAPI
    /home/pi/meh/go-ethereum-release-1.6/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters/api.go:75 +0x1c8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use POW, use Proof of Authority and problem solved. Reason being POA requires no DAG generation, therefore is suitable for low end devices.

Comment: Hi there. Can you add a few more details about how using Proof of Authority solved your issue? (And why you think it did.)

Comment: Reason being POA requires no DAG generation, therefore is suitable for low end devices. updated